# Does std::vector have to resize if the elements it contains grow in size?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stdvector

I apologize if this is too basic a question to ask here; I've been reading a bit about std::vector and I understand that it has to resize when the size reaches capacity. This can be an expensive operation if the objects it contains are large since it has to copy every one of them.

My question is: how does std::vector handle the actual size of the objects it contains growing? Suppose I initialize some

```
std::vector<Obj> vec(100);
```

And each Obj is initialized to something very small. But what if I then do something like

```
vec[14].ENGORGIO()
```

So that it now takes much more memory. Since the elements of std::vector are stored in contiguous memory, does this mean that it has to resize (expensively!)

To avoid this kind of thing, should I instead be storing pointers in a vector rather than the objects themselves? Like so

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Obj> > vec;
```

Thank you

Comment: Objects in C++ are fixed size. They can contain pointers to data, and these pointers can change to point to different sized data, but the objects themselves cannot change size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a data type in C++ is set at compile time and cannot change. The data type may contain references to other objects, and these other objects can vary in size, but the size of the reference, and thus the data type, is unchanging.

Consider a `vector` of `vector`s. The inner `vector` may contain 0 elements or billions and billions and it will always be the same size. The outer `vector` only knows that it contains 0 or more `vector`s and knows nothing about what is contained inside the inner `vector`s.

You do not have to worry about this.

Comment: Not quite accurate.   The size of references doesn't change either.   It's the size of what is referred to (like a dynamically allocated area of memory) that can change.

Answer (score 1):

Each type has a size, and all objects of that type have the same size. The size of an object never changes throughout the program. Therefore the scenario that you describe does not exist.

The way vector "resizes" without changing the size of the vector object is achieved through indirection. The elements are not part of the memory of the object. Instead, the vector points to a buffer in dynamic memory. Resizing is done by creating a bigger dynamic buffer, and copying the elements from the old one before destroying the old buffer.